# problems in findstr output to file

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I am trying following command

```
findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"" "index.html" >temp.txt
```

getting 
following out put

```
index.html:<img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a 
 href="MOD13Q1.A2018257.h25v06.006.2018282132046.hdf">
FINDSTR: Cannot open >temp.txt
```

it is not saving the output to temp.txt
other commands like

```
dir * >list.txt
```

are working fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have found one problem caused by the difference in quote handling between `cmd` parser and executable programs argument parsers.

While this is what seems correct

```
findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"" "index.html" >temp.txt
                        ^^                           escaped quote to findstr
            ^.............^ ^..........^             arguments to findstr
                                         ^           redirection operator
```

your problem is that when `cmd` tries to parse the line (to create the internal representation of the command and determine if a redirection is needed or not), as for `cmd` a double quote is a "escaped" (close and open again) quote, the quotes seen are

```
findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"" "index.html" >temp.txt
                         ^^ escaped quote
            ^ open          ^close     ^open
```

This implies everyting is seen as arguments to `findstr`

```
findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"" "index.html" >temp.txt
^.....^                                               command
        ^........................................^    argument
```

The escaped quote hides the redirection operator to `cmd` that passes evething to `findstr`.

Inside `findstr` the argument handling is different and it sees

```
findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"" "index.html" >temp.txt
            ^.............^ ^..........^ ^.......^    arguments to findstr
```

That means that the intended redirection is now seen as a file where to search.

One simple solution is to simply change the position of the redirection

```
>temp.txt findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"" "index.html"
```

**BUT** this leaves another problem. As it is quoted if the file name being processed by `findstr` includes spaces or special characters the command will fail because they are out of a quoted area.

So, we need a way to separate the two quotes, without including a non desired character in the `findstr` expression but properly closing each quoted area

```
findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"^" "index.html" >temp.txt
```

`^"` is seen by `cmd` as a real escaped quote out of a quoted area (closed by the preceding quote) so the `^` will not be passed to `findstr`. Now for `cmd` the quoted areas are

```
findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"^" "index.html" >temp.txt
            ^............^   ^..........^
```

The problematic quote is a escaped sequence that is handled as another character and `findstr` receives the intended arguments

```
findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"" "index.html" 
            ^.............^ ^..........^
```

Comment: bingo   >temp.txt findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"" "index.html"    worked, thanks

Comment: yes, your explanation explains it in details I feel findstr /RC:"h25v06.*hdf\"^" "index.html" >temp.txt is the better way